# CompareMem does not seem to work when using a value that came from an array

Tags: delphi

So I have a test case in my program

```
procedure MemCheck<T>(x, y : T);
var
    a, b : T;
    vals : array of T;
    c : T;
begin
    a := x;
    b := y;
    c := a;

    SetLength(vals, 4);
    vals[0] := a;
    vals[1] := a;
    vals[2] := a;
    vals[3] := a;

    c := T(vals[2]); //c := a ; workes fine 

    Check
    (
        CompareMem(@c, @y, SizeOf(T)),
        'Memory compare check'
    );


end;
```

This test case fails and I'm not sure why

`MemCheck<String>('a', 'a');`

it works fine when I use

`c := a ;` instead of `c := T(vals[2]);`

Comment: I've also tried using `Move(vals[2], c, SizeOf(T) )` which also produces the same bug

Comment: I can't see why the `CompareMem` function would care where the `c` value came from

Comment: It doesn't.  The compiler cares where the source of the `vals[2]` value comes from, and in this situation that is causing a memory allocation that is invalidating the subsequent comparison.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are passing string literals to `MemCheck()`.  Since they are the same value, the compiler merges them together in the executable.  So you are actually passing a single constant string literal to both the `x` and `y` parameters.  String literals are read-only and have a reference count of -1.  Assigning a string literal to a `String` variable copies the pointer to the memory block as-is without allocating new memory or incrementing the memory block's reference count.

Up to the point before you populate the `vals` array, your `a`, `b`, and `c` variables are just copies of the string literal pointer.  They are all pointing at the same data block in memory.  The `System.StringRefCount()` function confirms that they all return a reference count of -1, proving they are all pointing at a string literal.

In the statement `vals[2] := a;`, `a` is pointing at a string literal, so the RTL allocates a new `String` instance and copies the content of the string literal into the new memory block.  `a` still has a reference count of -1, but `vals[2]` now has a reference count of 1, proving that an allocation was performed.  The statement `c := T(vals[2]);` is then assigning an allocated `String` to a `String` variable, so the allocated data's reference count gets incremented.  `StringRefCount()` confirms that `c` now has a reference count of 2.

`CompareMem()` then consequently fails, because you are comparing the **value of the internal data pointer** of two `String` variables that are pointing at two different memory blocks, so their pointer values are different and the comparison fails.

When you change the statement `c := T(vals[2]);` to `c := a;`, `a` is still pointing at the string literal in memory, so that pointer gets copied as-is into `c` without performing any allocation.  Thus `CompareMem()` succeeds because now you are comparing the value of the internal data pointer of two `String` variables that are pointing at the same memory block, so the comparison succeeds.

So the real question is - why is the statement `vals[2] := a;` performing a new allocation instead of just copying the data pointer as-is like any other `String := String;` assignment?

The assignments `a := x;`, `b := y;` and `c := a;` are calling the `System.@UStrLAsg()` function, which permits a `String` pointing at a string literal to be assigned as-is to another `String` without performing an allocation.

The statement `vals[2] := a;` is calling the `System.@UStrAsg()` function instead, which *always* makes a new allocated copy when the source `String` is pointing at a string literal.

Why is the compiler choosing to use `@UStrAsg()` instead of `@UStrLAsg()` in the `vals[2] := a;` statement?  That is just the way the compiler works when the left-hand side of the assignment is a `String` inside a dynamic array, rather than a standalone variable.  If `vals` were a static array instead (`vals: array[0..3] of String;`), the compiler would choose to use `@UStrLAsg()` instead of `@UStrAsg()`, and `CompareMem()` would then succeed.

`@UStrLAsg()` is typically used when assigning a `String` to a *local* `String`, thus it is usually safe to allow a string literal to be used as-is.

`@UStrAsg()` is typically used when assigning a `String` to a *global* `String`, where a literal needs to be copied to avoid potential memory errors when the literal might exist in a DLL/Package that could be unloaded after the assignment.

So the compiler must be airing on the side of caution when assigning to a dynamic array as it does not know, or cannot assume, the lifetime of the `String` instances in the array.